# Geometric interpretation of del operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I know how to derive spherical del vector in spherical coordinates but I want to construct it for the spherical coordinates just by its geometric meaning so that I can generalise it for arbitrary coordinate.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) help ?

Comment: Are you interested in just the gradient of a scalar function or more general expressions involving $\nabla$ like divergences and curls?

Comment: Im interested in the most general or fundamental geometric interpretation of del operator